# How does DockerDefaultTargetOS set the container's OS in visual studio csproj?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, dockerfile

I'm trying to understand how the `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>` parameter in Visual Studio's csproj file works.

My understanding was that when building a docker image (docker build), the os of the image would be defined by the base image's os. So if my dockerfile looked like this `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-alpine` , then my container would be a linux container.

The strange thing is that I'm using `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base` as my base image in my dockerfile, and I can switch `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>` to `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>` freely and run this image in a container and it works.

So it seems like mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 contains both Windows and Linux images?
And the `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>` parameter is used by Visual studio to figure out which image to use?

Note:

Using `docker image inspect mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0` I can see that this image is either Linux or Windows depending on the container mode of my Docker Desktop. So if I switch docker desktop to Linux then `docker image inspect mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0` will tell me that the os is Linux.
This suggests that mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 can indeed point to both OSes